# Empty Table returned after minor modification to a Stored Procedure

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, datatable, oledb

**UPDATE** see end of OP

this one has us scratching our heads.

We have written a method in VB.NET that fills a DataTable

It does the following (simplified - code to instantiate or set items and error handling removed)

```
Dim procedureName As String
Dim mnCommandTimeOut As Integer
Dim parameters As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter()
Dim oConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
```

'... all the above will be set in intervening code. Then

```
Dim dataTable As System.Data.DataTable = Nothing
Dim oCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand = Nothing
oCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(procedureName, oConnection)
oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
oCommand.CommandTimeout = mnCommandTimeout

If parameters IsNot Nothing Then
    oCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters)
End If

Dim oAdapter As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = Nothing
oAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()
oAdapter.SelectCommand = oCommand    

oAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 120
oAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
oAdapter.MissingMappingAction = MissingMappingAction.Passthrough
dataTable = New System.Data.DataTable()

oAdapter.Fill(dataTable)
```

Please note that I have also left out the code to clean up after ourselves, disposing what we no longer need and so on. Our **real** code is cleaner than this!

**Here is the problem**

I have an SP that is called using the above method. Again I'm not going to go into any complexity but the code in the SP basically consists of something like

```
SELECT Column1,
       Column2
  FROM <somequery>
```

Now I needed to make a modification to this SP, and added a bit of complexity to it

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
       (Column1 <some type here>  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        Column2 <some type here>              NOT NULL)
```

Column types match original types

```
INSERT
  INTO @Table
      (Column1,
       Column2)
SELECT <modified query>
```

followed by

```
SELECT [TAB].[Column1],
       [TAB].[Column2]
  FROM @Table [TAB]
```

**To summarise** I have not yet made any significant changes to the SP, other than using the Table Variable. I don't do a direct **SELECT**, but instead I **INSERT INTO** the Table Variable and then I **SELECT** from that. I have not yet introduced any of the additional complexity I need; when I run the old SP and the new SP through SQL Server Management Studio I still get identical output **there**

But not through the above code in VB.NET

Using the old SP I get a System.Data.DataTable containing all the rows returned by the SP
Using the new SP I get a System.Data.DataTable containing 0 columns and 0 rows.

**no errors are raised** The code runs perfectly happily. It just returns an empty table.

It gets worse. We have another method that fills a DataSet. The only difference between it and the original procedure is that we define

```
Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet = Nothing
dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet()
```

and

```
oAdapter.Fill(dataSet)
```

And here's the insane bit. The utterly, incomprehensible **insane** bit.

When I run my modified SP through the **dataset** method, it returns a dataset. The dataset contains one datatable and guess what, the datatable contains all the data my SP returns.

I'm baffled. What on **earth** is going on? Anyone have a clue? I suspect it has something to do with me using a Table Variable, but what, how?

I know what you're going to say: Why don't we just use the DataSet method? Of course. But we have commitments to Backward Compatibility. There may be old versions of the code, calling my SP, using the old method. I designed my SP so that it still returns all the same data that old versions of the code expect. But I can't change old versions of the code. They still use the method that uses the DataTable. So I can't give them an SP that won't work **for them**.

Of course there is another solution. Leave the old SP unchanged. Write a new version of the SP, originalnamev2 or something like that, that's going to be used by the new software. But I'd rather avoid that. Plus, of course, this gives me the creeps. I need to understand **what** is not working anymore so I can assess whether there is anything else in our code base that I need to draw attention to.

**UPDATE** start

Ok - here is what I tried

1. Use a Table Variable @Table, insert rows in there, SELECT rows. **Result**: empty DataTable
2. Use a Fixed Table [dbo].[TestTable]. Obviously NOT a solution for production but I'm trying things out now. SP now does DELETE [dbo].[TestTable], INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] and finally SELECT rows. **Result**: empty DataTable
3. Finally I removed all the inserts and deletes from the SP, and only SELECT rows. **Result**: DataTable contains rows

Possible Conclusion: **It's the presence of DELETE and or INSERT statements that causes this behaviour.**

Now what do I need to do to make it work? Why does it not work when I use the Adapter to fill a DataTable, but it works if I use the same adapter to fill a DataSet?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you remove the TAB alias?

Comment: Thanks @JP .... I am afraid it doesn't :(

Comment: Further to this. I modified it so it used an actual Table, rather than a Table Variable. No luck.

I simplified it so I literally did a hardcoded insert into the Table Variable and then I SELECTed. No luck.

Comment: @JP I added an Update to the OP. Perhaps that will help explain what is going on?

Comment: Could it be because you use SelectCommand but it has inserts? Can you use SQLCommand instead.

Comment: Or alternatively use a CTE expression in a view and select from the view in stored procedure depending on how any input parameters are used

Comment: You might well be right about the SelectCommand..... I shall try that now and I'll let you know :)

Comment: @JP - Alas. The Adapter is a System.Data.OleDB.OleDBAdapter. It doesn't have a "SQLCommand" property. It has a SelectCommand, a DeleteCommand and an UpdateCommand property. I tried using UpdateCommand instead of SelectCommand but it made no difference. I had another gander through the Adapter properties but I don't see anything obvious that I might set to tell it to allow the SP to do Updates, Inserts or Deletes as long as it returns a data set....

Comment: Hello @JP

The problem went away after adding SET NOCOUNT ON to the start of the Stored Procedure. As suggested here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fbbdd4c5-a338-4591-8e73-17e8ef5d57c5/datatable-v-dataset-why-does-the-latter-work-when-the-former-doesnt?forum=sqldataaccess

Comment: Ah simple fix then!

Comment: @JP In the end... yes :) - still wondering why the functionality to fill a DataTable can't have the smarts to ignore the row count statements the same way the functionality to fill a DataSet can, but *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour was caused by my SP lacking a SET NOCOUNT ON statement at the top. Once I added this, it worked again.